# How to dynamic load XAML Page in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, dynamic, uwp

I need help with a change of perspective.

Recently, due to the company's business needs, it is necessary to migrate the existing Win32 software to the UWP platform. Because the software involves multiple devices, different devices have their own specific interfaces.

If the released software package directly includes all devices, the software package will be too large. Therefore, we want to enable the main software framework to support the operation of the corresponding device by downloading or additional installation when the user's related equipment is identified.

From the information found so far, this method is somewhat similar to the **Optional Package**. However, the actual experiment found that it can only support the separation of the back-end logic code, but not the XAML Page into the optional package.

Is there any way to separate the XAML Page and load it dynamically?

Comment: The behavior you expected is a bit complicated. It is difficult to separate xaml pages in uwp app. If you do want this, I suggest that you could write xaml contrlos in the code behind and package these code separat

Answer (score 0):

I'm also currently looking at solutions to load XAML Page dynamically in UWP. While I don't have a working solution yet it looks like I'm on the right track.

It seems [Windows Community Toolkit Sample App](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp) is loading XAML dynamically so all you should need is in that code base.